# Is there an allocation shortcut for collection members

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApi.Entities
{
    public class Account
    { 
        ...
        public List<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
        public List<Function> UserFunctions { get; set; }
        public List<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; };
    }
}
```

Is there a way in c# to tell compiler to allocate automatically new collections for all three members - so I don't have to type in `new List<>()` for each one of them?

Comment: In C# 9.0 and up you can take advantage of [target-typed `new`-expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator#target-typed-new): `public List<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; } = new();`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C# version 9+ you can use the [new() operator shortcut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator#target-typed-new):

```
public class Account
{ 
    ...
    public List<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; } = new();
    public List<Function> UserFunctions { get; set; } = new();
    public List<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Comment: And I'm just sitting here, hating how it doesn't work if I use `IList<T>` of course.

Comment: @Ray because it needs to know which concrete type should be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
public List<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; } = new List<Schedule>(); //from C# 6
```

or

```
public List<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; } = new();  //from C# 9
```